Ngxs : NullInjectorError No provider for PluginManager
i'm facing the problem with NGXS when I try to inject the store when I know in certain case it will not be provide by some applications : so I use the @Optional decorator to make it optional, but it seems not working because I have the error I mentionned on the title.
Here is the code :
@Component({
 selector: 'my-comp',
 standalone: true
})
export class Mycomponent {
 constructor(
  @Optional() private store: Store,
 ) {}
}

Note that, I have a standalone component that I use in different apps and one example app will not have the store provided in the app module this is why I need to do something like this.
Does anyone have any idea on how I can solve this injection problem ?

please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz where the issue happens

if you are using standalone components, you should import modules inside it. Store - it's a library, you need to import first.

@Component({ selector: 'my-comp',
standalone: true,
providers: [Store]  <- add this
})
